# Is there an event that fires when an Access table is updated?

Tags: events, ms-access-2010

I am familiar with control- and form-based events. Is there an event that fires, or a trigger that can be set, when a table in Access (2010) is updated?

What I am trying to do is monitor a specific field in a table for changes, then send an email or some other alert when this occurs.

I have tried browsing the KB but all events seem to be related to form operations, ex: when a form is loaded (On Load), when a combobox changes, etc.

Comment: Since this is Access 2010, look into [data macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973807(v=office.14).aspx)